# How does Django's transaction management keep track with methods that access DB?

Tags: django

Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) includes this snippet:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction

@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    create_parent()

    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            generate_relationships()
    except IntegrityError:
        handle_exception()

    add_children()
```

I assume `generate_relationships` also accesses the DB.

So when control flow changes from the `viewfunc` to `generate_relationships`, do DB statements from `generate_relationships` still occur in the same transaction?

Is it an not-recommended method, for example its difficult to test `generate_relationships` on its own?

Comment: yes, it will occur in the same transaction context

Comment: @Anentropic what happens when `get_relationships` is called as part of a test case?

Comment: If you call the function directly then it won't be in a transaction, only if you call viewfunc will it be in your atomic transaction context. If using Django's test case Django will wrap db access in test methods in a transaction, see the docs

Comment: Got it, with the part about savepoints too. I will accept it if you post those facts as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code in `generate_relationships` will execute under your atomic transaction context when the view function is called.

If you call the `generate_relationships` function directly in a test then it won't be in a transaction - the transaction context is defined in your view code.

If using Django's test case Django will wrap each test methods in a transaction, see the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase